# Flot Pie chart will not render when using small values

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I'm a total newbie when it comes to Flot Charting and I'm having a problem with my Pie Chart.

When I try to put a very small value inside the Flot dataset(refer below), it will make an error saying "Could not draw pie with labels contained inside canvas."

```
var pie_dataset = [
        { label:"Company1", data:1000.00, color: randomColor() },
        { label:"Company2", data:10000.00, color: randomColor() },
        ];

    var options = {
        series: {
            pie: {
                show: true,
                label: {
                    show: true,
                    radius: 180,
                    formatter: function (label, series) {
                        return '<div style="border:1px solid grey;font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:5px;color:white;">' +
                        label + ' : ' +
                        Math.round(series.percent) +
                        '%</div>';
                    },
                    background: {
                        opacity: 0.8,
                        color: '#000'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: false
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true
        }
    };
```

But when I change the value of "Compay2" = 1500.00, then it works perfectly.

Does Flot chart have restrictions like this?

Comment: how small is the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by two things. The first issue is because maybe the width and height you are using is not capable to fit the pie chart. The second issue is in the radius that you are using is too big to fit in the placeholder.

I set up a working example for your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9dVbb/2/), which includes 3 different ways of fixing your issue.

Solution #1

HTML:

```
<div id="placeholder1" style="width:600px; height:380px;"></div>
```

For the first pie chart, the only change I made was to increase the height.

Solution #2

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="width:800px; height:400px;">
    <div id="placeholder2" style="width:600px; height:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

For the second pie chart, the change is in having a container which has the placeholder for the chart. The container has a defined width and height, and then the placeholder uses a percentage of the height of the container.

Solution #3

HTML:

```
<div id="placeholder3" style="width:600px; height:300px;"></div>
```

JS:

```
options.series.pie.label.radius= 140;
```

For the third pie chart, the change is in having a smaller radius so as to fit it in a smaller placeholder.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. Unfortunately, the pie still broke when I changed `{ label:"Company2", data:10000.00, color: "red" },` with `{ label:"Company2", data:100000.00, color: "red" },`. As you can see, I changed its value from 10000 to 100000.